# AngularJS service returns data but when edited it edits the original service data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope

I've sort of accidentally written something that is working but I don't feel should be..!  Basically I have a list of items returned in JSON, the user can select one of them, edit it and save the change.  This is a reduced version of my code:

```
app.service("ItemData", ["$http", function ItemDataService($http) {
this.items = [];
var _this = this;

this.fetch = function() {
    var promise = $http.get("items.json");
    promise.then(
        function(payload) {
            _this.items = payload.data;
            console.log(_this.items); 
        }
    );
    return promise;
};

this.getFirstItem = function() {
    return this.items[0];
}

this.update = function() {
    console.log(this.items)
};
}]);


app.controller("PageCtrl", ["$rootScope", "ItemData", function($rootScope, ItemData) {

    var _this = this;
    $rootScope.item = null;

    var promise = ItemData.fetch();
    promise.then(
        function(payload) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $rootScope.item = ItemData.getFirstItem();
                $rootScope.item.name = "why does this change the original service?";
                ItemData.update();
            }, 5000);
        }
    );
}]);
```

When `ItemData.update` is called, the items that are logged show the change that I made.  But I was hoping `$rootScope.item` would be a copy rather than a reference to the original.  Isn't that standard with function return values?  Why is it editing my original as well here?

I'm new to AngularJS, and there might be better ways to do this, so my question is two part - why is the code doing what it is, and is there a better way anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic JS. It returns a reference to the object so when you change it, it will update "the root" as well. You can use [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to make a new version before you return it.